# Passing data from $ajax call to highcharts

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I have an ajax call

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '../../getdaily.php',
        type:'POST',
        dataType: '',
        success: function(output_string){
           console.log(output_string);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            console.log(xhr.statusText);
            console.log(thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

and the console.log will output...

```
[{"name":"Test-Cases","y":118},{"name":"White-Box","y":43},{"name":"Priority","y":44}]
```

I can easily paste this into my `data :` for highcharts and get the piechart I am looking for like so

```
...
series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Browser share',
        data: [{"name":"Test-Cases","y":118},{"name":"White-Box","y":43},{"name":"Priority","y":44}]
    }]
...
```

[image]

My question is how do I get the `output_string` into the Highcharts `data : <here>`. I have tried various ways of passing in as a variable and starting to spin out on this, not sure why.

The actual code I am using for highcharts and passing into an id...

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2014'
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                style: {
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Browser share',
        data: [{"name":"Test-Cases","y":118},{"name":"White-Box","y":43},{"name":"Priority","y":44}]
    }]
});
```

And to cover the php file, here is a partial of the end

```
...
$mysqli->real_query("SELECT priority FROM daily");
$rows2 = array();
$numb2 = 0;
$res2 = $mysqli->use_result();
$rows2['name'] = 'Priority';
while($r2 = $res2->fetch_assoc()) {
   $numb2+= $r2['priority'];
   $rows2['y'] = $numb2;
}

$result = array();
array_push($result,$rows);
array_push($result,$rows1);
array_push($result,$rows2);

echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just wrap your `highcharts` in a function, pass the ajax response as the function's argument and load the data (in argument) to your `high charts`, as:

```
function my_chart(response) {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        ...
        ...
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: response
        }]
    });
}
```

and call your function in ajax response, as:

```
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '../../getdaily.php',
            type:'POST',
            dataType: '',
            success: function(output_string){
               //call my_chart function
               var parsed_response = jQuery.parseJSON(output_string);
               my_chart(parsed_response);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                console.log(xhr.statusText);
                console.log(thrownError);
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: When using this I get close and previously had something similar, but get slice 0%, slice 0%... etc in my view. Somehow I am not formatting properly.

Comment: @Shane try using jQuery.parseJSON(output_string) before passing the data to high charts, as in my updated answer...

Comment: Yes this worked! Thank you much. Just needed to change your `,` to a `;` after `parseJSON(output_string)`