# Updating Highchart Series Data with Formatted AJAX Return

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, highcharts

I currently have a Highcharts scatterplot on my page that has the following structure:

```
  $(function() {

    $('#container').highcharts({

          /*chart options, etc... this does not change*/

          series: [/*there is some default data here*/]

      });
  });
```

This chart looks and works great. In addition, I have several checkboxes and a button on the page. When the button is pressed, I have some jQuery that looks at which checkboxes are checked, and sends this information to a PHP file that returns a NEW data series based on the selected checkboxes. That code looks like this:

```
    var Obj = {};
    $('button').click(function(e) {
        var tableIDs = $("#boxes input:checkbox:checked").map(function() {
            return $(this).val();
        }).get();
        var idClicked = e.target.id;
        Obj.tables = tableIDs;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'update.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                "points": JSON.stringify(Obj)
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);     /*for testing*/
            }
        });
    });
```

This code is at the very end of the script, and outside of my highcharts function. I have thoroughly tested the AJAX back-and-forth and everything is working just fine. The way the PHP is set up, the AJAX return is of the following format:

```
{name: 'series1', data: [[...,...],[...,...],...]},
{name: 'series2', data: [[...,...],[...,...],...]}
```

Not an array, just a very long string with lots of numbers in it (I put the above on two lines for clarity). In other words, it is formatted exactly as it needs to be within the 'series:' option of my Highchart. The number of series that my PHP returns changes depending on which/how many checkboxes are checked.

So, here's my question: What is the best way to replace my default data that is already displayed on my highchart with the new data returned by AJAX? Alternatively, the default data is optional, and can be removed if it makes this any easier.

There are quite a few similar questions out there but I seem to be having troule adopting other people's solutions to my issue. I have looked a few direct update solutions, such as those proposed by [rockStar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21560993/auto-update-highcharts-with-ajax) and [LeJared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12223972/load-data-into-highcharts-with-ajax), but I have not had any luck getting them to update the old data to the new data or inserting any data for that matter.

I particularly like the solution that was proposed by [DemoUser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28666481/passing-data-from-ajax-call-to-highcharts), basically passing data as a variable to a wrapped highcharts function. Here what that typically looks like:

```
function my_chart(data) {

    $('#container').highcharts({

        /*chart options, etc... this does not change*/

        series: [ /*there is some default data here*/ ]

    });
}
```

However, when I do this, it completely breaks my chart and I have been unable to get this working and passing properly.

Any suggestions/comments would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This part: `Not an array, just a very long string with lots of numbers in it` - is the problem. Can you return array (JSON) instead? I mean, it is a very nice string, but Highcharts needs an object to work with, not string :)

Answer (score 1):

Im doing it this way

```
var chart  = $('#container').highcharts();

if (chart) {
chart.series[0].setData([]);
}
```

That should clear the data from the chart.

I just noticed in my code that im recreating the chart from scratch for the new data  but i dont think that's necessary.

Once you get the new data try setting it again using

```
chart.series[0].setData([data]);
```